# can i put divs inside marquee element

Tags: html, css

i know that i can put text inside marquee or i can put images but i wonder if i can put blocks elements like div inside marquee like this

```html
<marquee>
<div>
other content
</div> 

<div>
other content
</div> 

<div>
other content
</div> 

<div>
other content
</div> 

</marquee>
```

what happened is that after i add more div and width of div become more than page width a problem occur that the div wrap and get out from the marquee , if i make a marquee hidden some div will disappear and will not show at all.

what should i do?

Comment: Just a little tip, try not to use `<marquee>` its very outdated and a pretty ugly element. Unless its to present something in a "old school" fashion I would stay away from it, there are better ways to present information (elements etc).

Comment: One thing. Marquee is not best way to animate blocks. You can use css animations http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Comment: hi ashot i don't want to animate divs i want a ticker with divs as content

Comment: No, because [you shouldn't even be using the `<marquee>` tag to start with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee).

Comment: j08691 it worked now and i marked the true answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your example above is that `div` is a block element and so has a default width of 100% of the parent. If you insist on using a `marquee` with `div`s you could change the display to `inline` or `inline-block`...

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<marquee>
<div>
other content
</div> 

<div>
other content
</div> 

<div>
other content
</div> 

<div>
other content
</div> 

</marquee>
```

Comment: thank you it works fine, but just a note maybe will be useful to others , first i put display:inline-block and float:left was there too, it didn't work when i remove float:left and keep display:inline-block; it works fine.